# How to encounter error when uploading an arff file in WEKA?

Tags: file, header, weka, notepad, arff

Hi Im using WEKA for data mining and i have a project based on kid's usage of internet.I have downloaded the data from openML in .arff form and im processing them in Notepad i have changed the values "," to "." and "?" to ",". Although when i try to open the file in WEKA i get this

"nominal value not declaired in header, read line 76"

line 76 is the first information after @data

Error:
[error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGbeM.png)

Comment: If you downloaded from OpenML as ARFF, then you should already have header/data sections. Check the [ARFF](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/arff_stable/) documentation for more background information on the data format.

Answer (score 0):

The [ARFF](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/arff_stable/) defines comma as the separator between columns. Replacing commas with periods essentially turned all columns into a single nominal value which wasn't defined for that column in the header. Nominal attributes require all possible values to be declared in the header section for that attribute.

What was the reason for converting commas to periods?